# How to enforce that a string must not be empty in Rust?

Tags: string, validation, rust

what is the easiest way to enforce that a field in a struct must not be an empty string ("")?

Example:

```rs
struct User{
   name: String,
   otherAttribute: Option<String>
}

user1 = User{"".toString(), "".toString()} //--> this should throw an error
```

I know I can implement the "new" trait for User and enforce special rules there but for large structs this is not a lot of fun.

Comment: One way could be to create a newtype `struct CustomString(String);` with deref impl and ensure that initailization functions exposed by this won't accept empty string. Then maybe use this newtype in place of string.

Comment: @Zeppi Would you mind to repost your comment in English, please?

Comment: @Zeppi, I just understand "excellent article" but after reading it I agree - very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @the-busybee, Sorry i didn't pay attention. "Here is an excellent article that supports the idea of <mihir-luthra>, https://www.worthe-it.co.za/blog/2020-10-31-newtype-pattern-in-rust.html"

Comment: I personally wouldn't create a custom string type for this. It's far easier to enforce these constraints in a custom constructor for the `User` type. If you keep the fields in the type private, the only way to create the type outside of the module it is defined in is using the constructor.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, I see your point but with large structs (more than 50 fields - all strings and all should have the same non-empty restriction), I end up writing the same restriction over and over again.
I'll post a solution based on the suggestions from MihirLuthra and Zeppi shortly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use this:

```rust
// in its own module
struct User {
    name: String,
    otherAttribute: Option <String>
}

impl User {
    pub fn new (name: &str, ...) -> Self {
        if name == "" {
            panic! (""); // or return None/Err
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

This will make User uncreatable from outside of the module it is located in, therefore the caller is forced to use `User::new` which validates the string. It will also make the calling shorter.

Comment: To access the variables, since they aren't marked with pub, you could create methods that return these values.